# voice activated circuit with static burst

Tags: audio, low-power

I would like to build a circuit that will activate when it detects a voice and when the voice stops to make a static burst sound like a voice activated radio.

What I am trying to do is make a voice amplifier for a Star Wars stormtrooper costume that will sound like a trooper from the movies.

I have an Aker MR1506 voice amplifier but it doesn't have a voice activated capability, it is always on. The microphone has a headphone jack that plugs into the amplifier. I would like to make a circuit the microphone plugs into and then plugs into the amplifier, unless someone thinks a complete amplifier circuit would be a better solution.

The circuit could either detect the voice and add the static burst once the voice stops or it could filter out anything below a certain dB, like breathing, and add the static burst after the voice stops. Anyone have any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: What sort of time delay after the voice stops are you expecting? If it is "short" how would you avoid it "breaking-in" to normal voice gaps?

Comment: I was thinking a 2 second delay would be sufficient and I would expect it to "break-in" during normal voice gaps if I paused that long.

Comment: Since everyone is "close the newbie's question" crazy today, two things I'd advise. First, what you want needs to be broken up into two sections. One is a `threshold detector` or `VOX circuit`. This passes the microphone audio, only if it passes a certain level of noise. Some are simple using some opamps and spare parts. The second part is the static sound. This is harder. Most likely will require either a sound recording module or a microcontroller. But the best advice, why no look on some movie prop forums or recreationist forums? There are tons of screen accurate kits and diy and help there

Comment: Also, one of the 501st group (Stormtrooper cosplayers) simply does the static sound, by blowing into the mic.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very broad and probably won't stay open, so I'll be brief.  I'd take the audio in, scale/shift as needed to go into the A/D of a micro, do amplitude detection in the micro, low pass filter that, add some hysteresis to detect voice on/off, and a time delay to ride out short pauses.  The hash sound could be always added to the amplifier input, just being quiet most of the time.  The micro should be able to produce a hash sound easily enough.

Comment: How were old VOX circuits made in the past? Isn't what I am looking for similar to if not the same as a 1960's era VOX radio microphone?

Comment: It is similar.  And Olin's description applies to the analog method as well, if you leave out the A/D part.  Doing it in a microprocessor saves parts, though.  And nothing here makes the static noise.  The micro could do that for you as well.